# A single word for "towards death"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which I cannot find anywhere in my saved vocab lists which means something like "having an orientation towards death" or "related to death". Not quite "fatalistic" but more "relating to death" in a neutral sense.

I'm almost certain I've read it in Nietzsche somewhere but can't find it in any paragraphs surrounding instances of the word "death".

It almost definitely starts with either an A, E, or O. It is not a compound word. It's an adjective (and I think it ends in "ic").

An example would be something like:

> The Freudian 'todestrieb' can be thought of as an ______ drive where ...

or

> His _____ philosophic interests were bound to result in a somewhat dejected and unenthusiastic attitude

Comment: *morbid* might fit your needs.

Comment: What about *gothic* ?

Comment: The word _thanatognomonic_ means 'signalling the nearness/approach of death' [[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/thanatognomonic)]; it is used (sometimes) in the medical domain. It is not included (!) in the [Wikipedia list of 'expressions related to death'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_expressions_related_to_death), but then there seems to be no synonym for _death-related_.

Comment: "thanatotic" means pertaining to Thanatos the personification of death; but it's so rare I'd be wary of using it (outside of specific contexts such as Freudian theory). https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thanatotic

Comment: The word you're looking for is just *death*. It means exactly what you're looking for, "not quite 'fatalistic' but more 'relating to death' in a neutral sense". And "Todestrieb", literally, means "death drive". You've already got the *drive* in your sentence, so all that's missing is *death*.